# SQL select column value with biggest number of duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates, max

I am having a problem I can't seem to solve. I have a data table that looks like this:

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbKEk.png

I need to select the ID_JOB value which is duplicated the most. In this particular example it would be ID_JOB = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt this  to your specific SQL implementation. Substitute [job_table] with the table you are querying.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID_JOB
FROM job_table
GROUP BY ID_JOB
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

You may need to add more ORDER BY logic in case a count "ties".

Comment: This was the right answer for me. Just a tip for those working with mysql this would be the code: SELECT ID_JOB FROM job_table GROUP BY ID_JOB ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1. Thanks.